# How do I solve $\log(x^k) = x$ algebraically?

Tags: logarithms

I'm am trying to solve $\log(x^k) = x$ algebraically. But I am at a complete loss. Is this even possible with basic algebra?

Comment: it's not possible with basic algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with the [Lambert W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) function.  By definition, $v=ue^u \Longleftrightarrow W(v) = u$.  So formally:
$$
\log(x^k) = x\\
x^k = e^x\\
x = e^{x/k}\\
1 = xe^{-x/k}\\
\frac{-1}{k} = \frac{-x}{k}e^{-x/k}\\
W\left(\frac{-1}{k}\right) = \frac{-x}{k}\\
-kW\left(\frac{-1}{k}\right)=x
$$

I said "formally" up there.  I did not take into account the possibility of different $k$th roots, or different branches of the Lambert W.

**added**
Here are graphs of $\log(x^5)$ and $x$.
[image: graphs]

And our solution with the two real branches of the W function:
$$
-5 W_0\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right) \approx 1.296\\
-5 W_{-1}\left(\frac{-1}{5}\right) \approx 12.71
$$
Complex non-real solutions are obtained using the other branches of W.

Answer (score 0):

take the LambertW function $$x=-k{\rm W} \left(-{k}^{-1}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with what most people call basic algebra, but if you allow the use of the Lambert W function it is possible.

Comment: And the remaining (total people - most people), what name they call "basic algebra" instead?